# How can I toggle dropdown list value from Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, drop-down-menu

In the below sheet I have a column called 'Loaned' (Column J) in which I have added a dropdown list to select either 'Yes' or 'No'.

[image]

But from a userform when I am entering a value to that field of either 'Yes' or 'No' it is being registered as text and the dropdown list is disappearing altogether. I do not want the dropdown list to go away instead I would like to write code which will enable me to toggle the value in that cell.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a similar issue in the internet, could anyone kindly help ?

Comment: Is your dropdown list based on `Range.Validation`?

Comment: @AntiDrondert I guess what you are asking is if my dropdown list is coded somewhere. If thats what it is, then no. I added the data validation in that column using the front end 'Data Validation' feature Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Worksheet_selectionChange event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 10 Then Exit Sub

    With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="YES,NO"
    Application.SendKeys "%{down}" '<~~ Pressing ( Alt + down arrow )
    End With
End Sub
```

Set the following in the sheet code.

[image]